# Elastic Search Results to POJO

Tags: java, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using spring-data-elasticsearch (version 4.0). Now I need to convert search results from rest high level client to POJO objects.

I would use ObjectMapper from Jackson library. I am sure there are better ways to do it.

Spring-data-elasticsearch now (from 4.0) uses MappingElasticsearchConverter. Unfortunately, I don't have an idea how to accomplish this - I don't see any relevant documentation.

**Entity**

```
@Document(indexName="addresses")
public class Address {

    @Id
    private String uam;

    @Field
    private String street;

    ....
}
```

I just need to convert SearchHits to Address entity

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "dev")
public class TestElasticSearch {


    @Autowired
    private RestHighLevelClient highLevelClient;

    @Test
    void convertToPojo() throws Exception {
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery());
        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
        SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

        SearchHit[] hits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();

        Arrays.stream(hits).map(hit -> hit.toString()).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Comment: why do you use the `@RestHighLevelClient`directly? You should use `ElasticsearchOperations` or repositories. That's what Spring Data Elasticsearch is for.

Comment: I like repositories, but I have some more difficult use cases (suggestions etc.). For now, I am more comfortable with RestHighLevelClient (a lot of documentation).
So this what I am trying to do is according to you generally bad practice?

Answer (score 3):

The SearchHits class extends Streamable class, so if you use ElasticsearchOperations like leiblix said, you don't even need to call `stream()` on it

```
    public <T> List<T> search(Query query, Class<T> clazz) {
        return elasticsearchOperations.search(query, clazz).map(SearchHit::getContent).toList();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As P.J.Meisch mentioned, is much better to use `ElasticsearchOperations`

```
void convertToPojo() {
    SearchHits<Address> hits = operations.search(Query.findAll(), Address.class);
    List<Address> addresses = hits.stream().map(hit -> hit.getContent()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to map it to SearchHits first and stream to POJO, cant we directly map the elastic result to List<Address>. ??

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution to this that is working well for me, and can work when you need a complex query that you can only get hits from, you can use

```
template.getElasticsearchConverter().read(YourPOJOClass.class, DocumentAdapters.from(hit));
```

where template is a `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate` you can get this injected into your class.